# Autosys command to retrieve jobs names, status only, using job_depends

Tags: autosys

I'm using job_Depends to retrieve forecast of jobs during a time period, I'm looking to find jobs OFF_ICE or OFF_HOLD only during a time period.
current query:

> job_depends -c -j %2 -F %3 -T %4>>%FileName%

brings out unnecessary(in my case) info., like showing the dependencies, conditions, etc.

```
                                     Start   Dependent
Job Name                         Status         Date Cond?        Cond?     Jobs?
--------                         ------      ---------------      -----   ---------
1CCS.UATQA.ACE_EXTRACT.C         ON_HOLD     Met                  No      Yes

   Dependent Job Name                            Condition
   ------------------                            ---------
   1CCS.UATQA.ACE_EXPORT.C                       SUCCESS(1CCS.UATQA.ACE_EXTRACT.C)
```

All I need is Job name and current status which are 'ON_ICE' and 'ON_HOLD' jobs only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ***find*** and ***findstr*** features to remove the unwanted stuff.
Add required words in the below command, according to your req. The below command will remove spaces and new lines too.

```
type Temp.txt | find /V "ON_ICE" | find /V "Condition" | find /V "-------" | find /V "success" | find /V "______"| find /V ".FW"| find /V "(" |FINDSTR /V /R /C:"^$">FilteredFile.log
```